# When I Programmatically download a text file, its content changes

Tags: vb.net, download, text-files

[image]I have a text file in the site that when I download it through Windows, and open the file on the system, its content is displayed correctly (it is what it was, pic1).

But when I download with the following piece of code, the content of the file changes (pic2).

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(remoteHashAddress, "c:\TbNetHashRemote.txt", "", "", False, 5000, True)
```

If you can help me to know where I am doing wrong, so that it is downloaded through vb or c# code snippet and the content does not change.

Comment: It has been compressed. `PK` is the signature for Zip files. The site is probably compressing it. Maybe save it as a ZIP file, then programatically decompress?

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I will do this. But if the site compresses the file, why is it not like this in picture 1?

Comment: Hm... I'm really not sure. Have you tried changing the extension of the 2nd file to .zip and opening it? What do you see inside when you do that?

Comment: If the remote server is using content compression, then I wonder if the Network.DownloadFile method does not know to decompress. Maybe you have to use the WebClient Class in your code instead.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: I changed the scenario and compressed the file that was on the site and uncompressed it after downloading, so the problem of changing the content was solved.